# Printing the file with number of hardlinks

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, find

I can print the number of hardlinks to files in directory by using `find . type f -printf "%f %n\n"`  but this will also print the hardlink not only original files:

Example:
  file1 is an original file.
  hardlink1 is a hardlink to the original file1.

Using this code It will print following :

`file1 2
hardlink1 2`

I want this problem to be solved only by using `find`. I want to print only the original file.

Comment: There is no _original_ file in hardlinking..

Comment: All hardlink files are same. So it will not make sense which one is original. At the max, you can check, which one is older than rest hardlink files. You can do so by many ways. (`stat` is one of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood how hard links work. There is no original. *All* files are simply hardlinks to an [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Therefore, hardlinks don't actually link to files, they link to inodes.

To illustrate, consider this file:

```
$ touch file
$ ls -li file
3282140 -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 May  3 16:27 file
```

As you can see above, `file` points to the inode `3282140`. Now, if we create a softlink to it:

```
$ ln -s file softlink
$ ls -li 
3282140 -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 May  3 16:27 file
3282141 lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 4 May  3 16:29 softlink -> file
```

The softlink is pointing to `file` but the link itself (which is also a filesystem object, another "file") has a different inode (`3282141`). However, if we create a hardlink, that will share the same inode:

```
$ ln file hardlink
$ ls -li
total 0
3282140 -rw-r--r-- 2 terdon terdon 0 May  3 16:27 file
3282140 -rw-r--r-- 2 terdon terdon 0 May  3 16:27 hardlink
3282141 lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 4 May  3 16:29 softlink -> file
```

So, if I now add some text to `hardlink`, it is exactly the same as though I added text to `file` itself:

```
$ echo "foo" > hardlink 
$ cat hardlink 
foo
$ cat file
foo
```

And, since `softlink` is pointing to `file`, I will see the contents of `file` if I `cat` it:

```
$ cat softlink 
foo
```

The same happens if I add text to `file`, `hardlink` and `file` are equivalent:

```
$ echo bar >> file
$ cat hardlink 
foo
bar
```

Now, if I delete `file`, `softlink` will be a broken link but `hardlink` won't be affected:

```
$ rm file 
$ ls -li
total 4
3282140 -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 8 May  3 16:33 hardlink
3282141 lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 4 May  3 16:29 softlink -> file
$ cat softlink 
cat: softlink: No such file or directory
```

Since the link's target has been removed, the softlink is broken. The hardlink, however, is still there since it was pointing to the same inode:

```
$ cat hardlink 
foo
bar
```

All this is to say that there is simply no way to differentiate a hardlink from the file it was created to point to because, unlike softlinks, it wasn't actually created pointing to a file. All files are hardlinks pointing to an inode of the file system. In fact, deleting a file simply removes the link to the inode. It doesn't actually remove the data. The system keeps a count of the links pointing to each inode and simply considers inodes available for writing if the link count is 0.

What you can do, is find all links pointing to an inode and delete all but one. If we go back to where we were at the beginning:

```
$ rm *
$ touch file
$ ln file hardlink
$ ls -l file hardlink
-rw-r--r-- 2 terdon terdon 0 May  3 16:39 file
-rw-r--r-- 2 terdon terdon 0 May  3 16:39 hardlink
           ^
           |---- the number of links
```

The output of `ls -l` includes the number of links pointing to an inode. Therefore, you can iterate over its output (this is one of the few cases where parsing `ls` is safe) and delete any files with a link number >1:

```
for file in *; do [ $(ls -l $file | cut -d' ' -f2) -gt 1 ] && rm "$file"; done
```

That will delete all hardlinks but one, as long as all the hardlinks are in the same directory.

Further reading: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/04f/notes/links_and_inodes.html

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot of understanding how hardlinks and softlinks works. I'm going to read further about it ( starting with link you have posted ).